# Illustrator pattern brush: Modifiying anchor point stretches shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, brush

I generated a pattern brush and when I draw a path and move one anchor end point with the direct selection tool then the shape of my pattern brush is stretched or shrunk like the circle in this picture (bottom).

However, if I change the size of the path via the normal selection tool then it's fine (middle).

[image]

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3):

In all honesty, I'd just use a standard stroke with an **Arrowhead**. Specifically **Arrow 24**.... part of the standard AI install. You can set the stroke to have the arrowhead on both ends.. and well.. it'll scale with the stroke weight and offer more control over the size of the circles.

[image]

But.. if you *really want* a brush.....

You would be better served by an **Art Brush** for that artwork if the desire is to keep the circles *always* circles.

[image]

Drag the two circles and the path to the Brush panel....

[image]

Choose "Stretch Between Guides" for the Brush Scale Options

[image]

And then drag the guides (dotted lines) in the preview window so they are inside the circles...

[image]

You can then draw any length or curve and the circles will remain circles.

(if you get a "wonky circle" it means the end anchor point is a smooth point rather than a corner point. Convert *that* end anchor point to a corner point and the circle should straighten out.)

Comment: Thanks for that very detailed answer.
Yes for only circular ends I would use the arrowhead selection, but the intention is to generate a more complex shape. I just wanted to try out how the brush generation works. So the art brush is the best choice for my purpose.

Comment: I just tried out the arrow 24 but this doesn't work for me as it has a white filling. But I need it transparent.

Comment: Ahh.. I see that now. Then I'd edit the arrow head :)